# What is the absolute risk of blood clots in pregant women?

Tags: obstetrics, blood-clotting

What is the *absolute* risk of blood clots around pregnancy, and by what factor the base risk is increased by the main risk factors?

Comment: Thank you for the edit, but now we run into problem #2 with your question. It lacks prior research, and that's required of questions here, as it is on most of the science and academic sites.